# Linux Swap Usage Oneliner with numerical only output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, swap

I'd like to get a Linux bash one liner which will echo out the current SWAP in use (can be in kB, KB, MB). I only need the numbers, no text descriptions or any of the other RAM information... tried using Google, but it seems no one has requested this before.

A 2 - 5 line script would work as well, though I'll favor a one-liner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one liner will give the used swap based on subtracting the free swap from the total swap:

```
grep -E '^Swap[TF]' /proc/meminfo | awk 'p{print p-$2}{p=$2}'
```

The `grep` extracts the relevant lines from `/proc/meminfo` and the `awk` subtracts the two values.

**edit:** removed a `$3` from the end of the `awk` print statement as the OP stated they just wanted the number. This number will be in KB.

Comment: Greatly appreciated... I've been using /proc/meminfo, but I hadn't figured out how to clean it up 100%. Thanks!